# Ubuntu launcher space problem

Tags: unity, launcher

Recently on Ubuntu-14.04 launcher starts consuming space from left hand side even tough auto hide is enabled see below image for details.

[image: Ubuntu Launcher Problem]

As we can see from above image launcher took space even though it's not visible.

Note: Space on left hand side is same as launcher width.

I  would like to remove space from left hand side i.e. all GUI must be drawn on entire screen instead of sub parts.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by docky. One more instance of docky was created, I was not aware of this. After some time I tried to create one more instance which reveals this problem and I deleted entry corresponds to new docky and it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the top bar of your window and drag it flush left or click on the [] green button to make it full screen.

Comment: It's not working. Why since all buttons (close, minimize, magnify) all are  at top left corner. Which can be see in the Image.

Comment: Ok try this: system settings>appearance>behavior>show the menus for a window, select **in the window's title bar**.

Comment: couldn't find such setting.  The space left in left hand side is same as the launcher width

Comment: OK, put your cursor to the left edge of the screen to get your launcher back, click on the dash (swirl at the top to get the search function) enter "system settings" and follow the steps above.

Comment: No, It's not working.